# Matching routes with MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following URLs

1. URL/description
2. URL/Home/Member/description
3. URL/Home/description

Here are my routes

For #1 above:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DescriptionNoController",
                url: "{d}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", d = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

For #2 above:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DescriptionDefault",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{d}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", d = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

I'm having troubles with #3.

I thought I could do

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DescriptionDefaultNoAction",
                url: "{controller}/{d}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", d = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

But this creates an endless loop. Basically I want the #3 example to map "home/description" to the Home Controller and Index action. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that scenario 3 will match with Route config 2, as it will think that the description is the action, and you have no {d} part.

The only way around this is to have very specific routes, and you need to cater for scenario 3  before scenario 2.

The last route you should ever add would be that this one, which is your catch all.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DescriptionDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{d}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", d = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

What is not clear from your question is whether the description part of your url is a placeholder or literal value. If literal, then make use of that in your route config.